# Show hidden nested tables in jQuery with selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have html with several nested tables (in this example only one is nested):

```
<table class="toptable" border="1">
    <tbody>                   
        <tr class="accordion">
            <td>TD1</td>
            <td>TD2</td>
            <td>TD3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            <table class="nested" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>nestedTD1</td>
                        <td>nestedTD2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>nestedTD3</td>
                        <td>nestedTD4</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery allows me to show/hide second row of main table by clicking on the first row.

```
$(function() {
  $(".toptable tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
  $(".toptable tr:first-child").show();
  $(".toptable tr.accordion").click(function(){
  $(this).nextAll().fadeToggle();
    });
  });
```

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbag/pAxry/1/

My problem is that only first row of the nested table is showing. I suppose that problem in the tree traversal on the jquery; I've tried to change `nextAll()` to `find("*")`, but it's not working.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the first selector that hides the table rows. Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pAxry/2/)):

```
$(function () {
    $(".toptable > tbody > tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
    $(".toptable tr:first-child").show();
    $(".toptable tr.accordion").click(function () {
        $(this).next().fadeToggle();
    });
});
```